# Remove characters preceding first instance of a capital letter in string in R

Tags: regex, r, substring, uppercase

I'm trying to remove all characters preceding the first instance of a capital letter for each string in a vector of strings:

```
x <- c(" its client Auto Group",  "itself and Phone Company", ", client Large Bank")
```

I've tried:

```
sub('.*?[A-Z]', '', x)
```

But that returns:

```
"uto Group"  "hone Company"   "arge Bank"
```

I need it to return:

```
"Auto Group"    "Phone Company" "Large Bank"
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: `sub("^.*?([A-Z])", "\\1", x) `

Comment: Thanks Wiktor! Can you add as an answer so I can accept? Also, what does the "\\1" mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a capturing group with a backreference:

```
sub("^.*?([A-Z])", "\\1", x)
```

Here,

- `^` - start of the string
- `.*?` - any 0+ characters as few as possible
- `([A-Z])` - Capture group 1 capturing an uppercase ASCII letter that will be referenced with `\1` in the replacement pattern.

So, what we restore what we captured in the result with a backreference.