# removing string before the fist uppercase

Tags: r

I have a string **"x --Detroit Tigers"**, and I want to remove all characters before the first uppercase，in other words，I want **"Detroit Tigers"**. How can I do that in R?

Comment: Answered here already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37842146/remove-characters-preceding-first-instance-of-a-capital-letter-in-string-in-r

Comment: @cardinal40 When you see a question that is a duplicate of another one, you should flag it as a duplicate instead of just posting a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Or in base R

```
sub(".*?([A-Z])", "\\1", String)
[1] "Detroit Tigers"
```

Details:

```
 .*?     makes a _non-greedy_ match of everything until ...
 [A-Z]   matches an upper case character
```

Because [A-Z] is enclosed in parentheses, the matching character is stored in a capture group. Everything from the match is replaced with "\1", the contents of the first capture group - in this case, the first capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

if all your strings have the same structur, you can use `str_sub()` from **stringr**.

```
library(stringr)
s <- "x --Detroit Tigers"

str_sub(s, 5, 50)
# [1] "Detroit Tigers"
```

if not, you have to identify the first uppercase

```
first_upper <- which(grepl("[[:upper:]]", strsplit(s, "")[[1]]) == TRUE)[1]

str_sub(s, first_upper, 50)
# [1] "Detroit Tigers"
```